# If $f: R \rightarrow S$ is a ring homomorphism and $J$ is an ideal of $S$, prove that $I=\{i \in R: f(i) \in J\}$ is an ideal of $R$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

Let $f: R \rightarrow S$ be a ring homomorphism and let J be an ideal of S. Prove that $I=\{i \in R: f(i) \in J\}$ is an ideal of R.

So originally I thought I was correct and assumed that this is akin to saying that the inverse of $f$ produces I? But @layabout mentioned this is a wrong assumption.

Looking for help. I can see how to prove $J$ is an ideal if we knew $I$ was an ideal, but I don't know how to do this in reverse without using $f^{-1}$.
I am wondering if there is some trick by using the theorem

> Every ideal of a ring R is the kernel of a ring homomorphism of R. In particular, an ideal A is the kernel of the mapping $r \rightarrow r + A$ from $R$ to $R/A$

Below is my first attempt, but is wrong because I cannot assume $f^{-1}$

Let $x,y \in f^{-1}(J)$
Meaning $f(x), f(y) \in J$
We can also say from homomorphisms that:
$f(x)+ f(y) \in J$ and $f(x+y) \in J$
Which means $x,y \in f^{-1}(J)$

Now let $x \in f^{-1}(J)$ and $a \in R$
then $f(a)\in J$ and $f(a) \in S$ 
and definition of ideals, that is $\forall r \in S$ and $\forall j \in J$, the product of $rj \in J$
$f(x)f(a) \in J$ 
and by homomorphism $f(xa) \in J$ 
Which means $xa \in f^{-1}(J)$
Which means $f^-1(J)$ is an ideal of $R$
and since $f^-1(J)$ produce $I$, $I$ is an ideal of $R$

Comment: You can't assume that $f$ is invertible-maybe you do realize this, and this is what you mean when you say 'akin to saying...'. The term that applies to $I$ is that it is the preimage of $f$

Comment: @layabout Oh I didn't realize this.

Comment: @layabout Can you explain to me why I cannot assume this?

Comment: The notation "$f^{-1}(J)$" refers to the preimage of $J$ under $f$. It doesn't mean that $f^{-1}$ exists.

Comment: @Ehsaan So does that mean if I replace "$f^{-1}$" with "preimage of $f$" I would have a correct proof?

Comment: No, your proof looks perfectly fine! I was just replying to your previous comment --- you can't assume that $f$ is invertible. Many people believe that the notation "$f^{-1}(J)$" indicates that $f$ is invertible, which is incorrect.